# R stack three plots with equal heights

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to stack 3 plots using the standard plot command in R. So far I have achieved the following:

[image: three stacked plots]

using the following data:

```
t30DC_diff = c(12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6)
t50DC_diff = c(14, 16, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 6)
t90DC_diff = c(24, 24, 26, 22, 28, 24, 20, 20, 20, 18, 18, 18, 18, 16, 18, 14, 16, 16, 18, 16)

t30DC_sd = c(3.45, 2.62, 2.23, 1.93, 1.3, 1.03, 0.98, 0.78, 0.58, 0.9, 0.98, 0.98, 0.78, 0.85, 1.24, 1.44, 1.44, 1.59, 1.59, 1.73)
t50DC_sd = c(4.52, 4.79, 3.67, 3.09, 2.23, 1.78, 1.73, 1.34, 1.48, 1.51, 0.9, 1.59, 1.44, 1.51, 1.34, 2.23, 2.26, 2.26, 2.33, 2.15)
t90DC_sd = c(7.65, 7.88, 9.84, 7.14, 7.33, 6.82, 6.26, 6.16, 6.02, 5.66, 5.21, 5.66, 5.42, 5.25, 5.15, 4.6, 5.29, 5.22, 5.56 , 5.08)
```

and the following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,1),
    mar = c(0, 2.7, 3, 2.5),
    mgp = c(1.7,0.6,0))
plot(t30DC_diff, pch = 16, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Depth (mm)", ylab = "Time (ns)",
     main = "", cex.lab = 1.2,
     ylim = c(0, max(t30DC_diff) + 2),
     xlim = c(0,21),
     xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
     cex.axis = 0.75,
     xaxt = 'n',
     cex.lab = 0.9)
points(t30DC_sd, pch = 4, col = "black")
legend("top", 
       pch = c(16,4), 
       col = c("blue", "black"),
       legend = c("Largest Difference", "Standard Deviation"),
       cex = 0.9,
       horiz = T)

par(mar = c(0, 2.7, 0, 2.5))
plot(t50DC_diff, pch = 16, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Depth (mm)", ylab = "Time (ns)",
     main = "", cex.lab = 1.2,
     ylim = c(0, 18),
     xlim = c(0,21),
     xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
     xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n',
     cex.axis = 0.75,
     cex.lab = 0.9)
axis(side = 2,
     las = 1,
     at = seq(0,16,2),
     cex.axis = 0.75)
points(t50DC_sd, pch = 4, col = "black")

par(mar = c(3, 2.7, 0, 2.5))
plot(t90DC_diff, pch = 16, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Depth (mm)", ylab = "Time (ns)",
     main = "", cex.lab = 1.2,
     ylim = c(0, 30),
     xlim = c(0,21),
     xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
     cex.axis = 0.75,
     cex.lab = 0.9,
     yaxt = 'n')
axis(side = 2,
     las = 1,
     at = seq(0,25,5),
     cex.axis = 0.75)
points(t90DC_sd, pch = 4, col = "black")
```

I am trying to get the middle plot to have the same height as the other two plots. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks to the answer by the user @rawr, the new code which works is:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,1),
    mar = c(0, 2.7, 0, 2.5),
    mgp = c(1.7,0.6,0),
    oma = c(3, 0, 3, 0))
plot(t30DC_diff, pch = 16, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Depth (mm)", ylab = "Time (ns)",
     main = "", cex.lab = 1.2,
     ylim = c(0, max(t30DC_diff) + 2),
     xlim = c(0,21),
     xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
     cex.axis = 0.75,
     xaxt = 'n',
     cex.lab = 0.9)
points(t30DC_sd, pch = 4, col = "black")
legend("top", 
       pch = c(16,4), 
       col = c("blue", "black"),
       legend = c("Largest Difference", "Standard Deviation"),
       cex = 0.9,
       horiz = T)

plot(t50DC_diff, pch = 16, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Depth (mm)", ylab = "Time (ns)",
     main = "", cex.lab = 1.2,
     ylim = c(0, 18),
     xlim = c(0,21),
     xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
     xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n',
     cex.axis = 0.75,
     cex.lab = 0.9)
axis(side = 2,
     las = 1,
     at = seq(0,16,2),
     cex.axis = 0.75)
points(t50DC_sd, pch = 4, col = "black")

plot(t90DC_diff, pch = 16, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Depth (mm)", ylab = "Time (ns)",
     main = "", cex.lab = 1.2,
     ylim = c(0, 30),
     xlim = c(0,21),
     xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
     cex.axis = 0.75,
     cex.lab = 0.9,
     yaxt = 'n')
axis(side = 2,
     las = 1,
     at = seq(0,25,5),
     cex.axis = 0.75)
points(t90DC_sd, pch = 4, col = "black")
```

The output of this is:

[image: updated image]

Comment: use outer margins (`par(..., oma = c(3, 0, 3, 0))`) for the top/bottom and set all top/bottom `mar` to 0 like the center figure

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I have edited the question to show this answer.

Comment: @rawr you should turn your comment into an answer.